# How to change colour of specific points in ggtern

Tags: rgb, ggtern

I am using ggtern to graph some RGB data, where each point refers to the colour % from red, green or blue.

I was wondering if it is possible to change the colour of specific plot points to match the actual colour which they are representing?

I have tried using some ggplot2 commands but it doesn't work.

This is what I am using now:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtern)
library(readxl)
Image9 <- read_excel("~/PhD/Image9.xlsx")
View(Image9)
ggtern(data=Image9, aes(x = Blue, y = Red, z= Green )) + geom_point( size=2, 
shape=16, color="black") + theme_rgbw() + theme_hidegrid_major() +
 theme_hidetitles()+ theme_rotate(degrees = 120) + 
 geom_text(aes(label=Colour), size=3, color="black", hjust=0, vjust=0)
```

Using this command I can plot the data as a colour intensity percentage in Red, Green and Blue and label the points so that I can map them back to the original image
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsxRi.png); representative image of plot. 
Ideally I would like to plot each point as the same shade of color which they represent within the color space, I don't know if this is possible with this package.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us a minimum complete verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think the trick with this one, without seeing any kind of working example, is to map each point in your dataframe to to the actual colour representation (hex code), and then use the `scale_fill_identity(...)` or `scale_colour_identity(...)`